# Ehat is the space complexities of recursive and dynamic programming approaches of binomial coefficient?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, data-structures, space-complexity, binomial-coefficients

I saw that the space complexity when using dynamic programming approach(Pascal's triangle) is O(n^2). What about the space complexity in recursion approach?

Comment: DP solution can be done in O(n) space complexity, since you only need to keep the current and previous lines, and not the entire matrix.

Comment: What if we implement the whole pascal triangle....then we will need a 2d matrix. Am I right??